# Call a method from activity that extends View

Tags: android, image, methods, call

I'm doing a genre of a bull's eye, but instead of use circles I'm using squares.

But the problem is:

Everything is done, the algorithm to generate the color the others squares is done.

But I implemented a button, and I made it to refresh the bull's eye.

The problem is that I can't make, need help.

This is the MainActivity, it's from here that I will detect the button click.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame);

    Draw draw = new Draw(this);
    frame.addView(draw);

    Button refresh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.refresh);

    refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            draw.onDraw(canvas);
            frame.addView(draw);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
    }
}
```

And this is the Draw activity, this is the one that I used to render the image.

```
public class Draw extends View {

public Draw(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

Paint prop = new Paint();
Random color = new Random();

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();

    int oriwidth = 0;
    int oriheight = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
        int red = color.nextInt();
        int green = color.nextInt();
        int blue = color.nextInt();
        prop.setARGB(0, red, green, blue);
        canvas.drawRect(oriwidth += 10, oriheight += 10, width -= 10,
                height -= 10, prop);
    }
}
}
```

Can someone help me? Sorry for the english.

Comment: What is the exact problem. You have mentioned "The problem is that I can't make, need help." Is it a compile or runtime issue?

Comment: I can't call the method onDraw to run again. I want that to see a new square with new colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any special reason why you're adding the Draw view programmatically during onCreate?
Try defining the Draw view in the layout xml itself. That should solve any issues with defining the width / height of the view (make sure to define width & height... try hard coded dimensions at first like 100dp by 100dp)

Once you've done that, make sure to capture your "draw" view as a member of the activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
private Draw mDraw;
```

Then, in your onCreate:

```
mDraw = (Draw)findViewById(R.id.myDrawId);
```

Then, in your button click listener, just call invalidate:

```
refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mDraw.invalidate();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks man! I just needed to have the invalidate method. I've learned something! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change with this portion of code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
     MainActivity.this.draw.onDraw(canvas);
     MainActivity.this.frame.addView(draw);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call `onDraw()` directly. Try `draw.invalidate()`.

Comment: He tells me to change the draw.onDraw(canvas); and frame.addView(draw); modifier to final. And when I do that. I click on the refresh button and it crashes. And it stills don't work.

Comment: Okay, you don't need to call `frame.addView()` again in your OnClickListener, the view is already added at that point. Try removing that line from the listener.